# Same query, different outcome

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query which I first typed out like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS development $$

CREATE PROCEDURE development()

BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
WHILE i <= 500 DO
IF NOT EXISTS ((SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = 500)) THEN     INSERT INTO customers (firstName) VALUES (''); END IF; 
SET i = i + 1; 
END WHILE; 
END $$

CALL development() $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS development $$

DELIMITER ;
```

but then "compressed" into this:

```
DELIMITER $$ DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS development $$ CREATE PROCEDURE development() BEGIN DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1; WHILE i <= 500 DO IF NOT EXISTS ((SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = 500)) THEN INSERT INTO customers (firstName) VALUES (''); END IF; SET i = i + 1; END WHILE; END $$ CALL development() $$ DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS development $$ DELIMITER ;
```

on one line. The problem is that the first (multiline) code works, and does what it's supposed to do, while the other (single line) version, doesn't. It doesn't fail or throw errors, it just doesn't insert the rows like the multiline version. Why is this? More importantly, how can I make the single line version work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what way does it fail?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It doesn't fail, it just doesn't do what it's supposed to do; that is, adding 500 customer dummy rows.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the delimiters, which go at the end of a line.  However, you don't explain what the problem is, so that is just a guess.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm unsure of the exact problem at hand here. All I know is that both code versions is identical in the sense of content, but somehow manages to provide a different outcome. I was hoping somebody could share some light as to what may be causing this. Delimitirs, you say? What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0):

please try it this way:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS development $$ CREATE PROCEDURE development() BEGIN DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1; WHILE i <= 500 DO IF NOT EXISTS ((SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = 500)) THEN INSERT INTO customers (firstName) VALUES (''); END IF; SET i = i + 1; END WHILE; END $$ CALL development() $$ DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS development $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The last line break might not be neccessary.

But I am fairly confident that, when inlining the whole code you end up setting a delimiter much longe than "$$"

I just executed the completely inlined example on a random sql server of mine and always received a positive result, even though I have not set up the related db structure.

with line breaks there are complaints about missing tables (as would be expected)

Regards
Stefan

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution for me since it is absolutely compulsory for the query to be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run any SQL on the same line as `delimiter`. `delimiter` is a built in mysql client command that sets the statement seperator, not an sql interpreter. It takes one argument, read up to the first space or newline. Everything else is ignored.

```
delimiter $$ select now() $$
```

No output, because everything after $$ is thrown away.

Or illustrated by bad syntax

```
delimiter "$$" select; nothing order by from nowhere group , oh forget it $$
```